# Running a DBLink INSERT query using Psycopg2, running into formatting problems

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2, dblink

I'm trying to insert into a remote database using DBLink, and I'm making the query through Psycopg2. This is my code that takes a list of column names called `fields` and a list of column values called `values`:

```
    fields_str = ",".join(fields)
    values_str = ("%s, " * len(values))[:-2]

    query = """SELECT dblink_exec('{0}', 'INSERT INTO {1} ({2}) VALUES ({3});'""".format(self.foreign_db,
                                                                            table,
                                                                            fields_str,
                                                                            values_str)
```

This doesn't work because DBLink expects two single quotes around every string value like in the example in their documentation: `SELECT dblink_exec('myconn', 'insert into foo values(21,''z'',''{"a0","b0","c0"}'');');`

The problem is that Psycopg2 sticks an "E" in front of all my strings to escape them. That means neither adding single quotes around all my values nor adding single quotes around all my "%s" parts in my query can fix this. The general problem seems to be that Psycopg2 cannot properly handle escaping strings within a DBLink query string.

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "f5907160"
LINE 1: ...ar,tag,oid,objecttype,updatedat,usedat) VALUES (E'f5907160-4...
```

Any way around this?

Comment: Does this have something to do with http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-compatible.html#GUC-STANDARD-CONFORMING-STRINGS ? What about writing a PostgreSQL function to do the work and calling it from python? Pass values and field names as parameters.

Comment: @Jayadevan Yes, I think the double single quotes are there for the reason described on that page. The PostgreSQL function is a good idea. I'd rather not do that since I don't really understand PostgreSQL functions, but I'll go for it if I can't figure this out on my Python script.

Comment: Oops, I had opened several tabs and looked at the wrong Postgres manual page. You mean the "E", I'm assuming. Yes, it also has to do with that. Psycopg2 seems to expect that I can escape strings with "E", but I can't do that inside DBLink queries. In general, Psycopg2 (understandably) doesn't know how to handle escaping within a DBLink query string.

Comment: I was referring to "E".